# shout I cancel every ajax request in componentWillMount()?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-native, request, axios

due to avoid memory leaks, should I cancel every ajax request before component unmounts? I'm using axios and it feels like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to cancel all the subscriptions before component unmount.